# 1990s film, knockoff of Alien and Predator franchises, included a jetpack and a fanged frisbee

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a group of people (soldiers?) stuck in a jungle and attacked by two different sorts of aliens. One looked a lot like the Xenomorphs from the *Alien* movies, very bestial. The other was a humanoid armored creature  like in *Predator* films which I remember had a jetpack, and might have had a thrown weapon that looked like a fanged frisbee. I distinctly remember the jetpack bit happened on a bridge.

<strike>After that, my memory gets very fuzzy right up until the end credits which featured the aliens (both? Maybe just the Xenomorph ones) on a talk show. I vaguely remember TV Tropes mentioning this, and that vague memory suggests it was originally a Swedish movie.</strike>

I would have watched it on TV somewhere between 1994 and 1998, possibly on a premium cable channel as I think I watched it while at All State Choir, where they bunked us up in hotels and frequently forgot to shut down the premium channels.

<strike>I'm pretty sure that the English title had the word "Alien" in it, and I think it was just a two word title.</strike>

Trish Ling clued me in that the talk show bit is from a totally different movie than the first movie, which is the one I was really looking for, so I've struck out those bits.

Comment: "Alien vs Hunter" leaps to mind, but there was nothing about a talk show in it.

Comment: @Omegacron: Plus, the timeframe is way off on that. :)

Comment: Alien vs. Krull?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: I thought the same thing right after typing in "fanged frisbee" but that's really what comes to mind. It was a disc-like weapon, thrown, with sharp points along the edges.

Comment: Was gonna suggest [Evil Aliens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_Aliens) which ends with an alien talk show, but it's too recent (2005).

Comment: @TrishLing
That's the talk show, but not the first part. Dang it... that means I have two movies I was thinking of, which means my remembered info for the first is very small.

Comment: FuzzyBoots on TVtropes is you isn't it? :)

Comment: Yes... yes it is. :)

Comment: Pretty sure I saw this film - additional information if it matches up: the soldiers came across a military base in the jungle, and in the end it turns out the predator type alien was working with them, fighting the outbreak of alien species which resulted from an accidental space ship crash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

[Code Red - The Rubicon Conspiracy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0266414/?ref_=fn_al_tt_10).

Summary from [TVTropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/CodeRedTheRubiconConspiracy):

> *Code Red: the Rubicon Conspiracy* is a 2001 TV movie aired by UPN involving a dishonorably discharged Army Lieutenant by the name of Peter Doyle (played by Brian McNamara) who is called in for a rescue mission regarding the Rubicon Station in the midst of Africa. His brother, James Doyle, may be the last remaining member of the last mission squad. He was also the reason for Peter's discharge, The Rubicon Station has a nuclear failsafe due to detonate in 20 hours if it's not reset and there are local rebels in play. Furthermore, Doyle quickly learns that some of his opposition is not from this planet, but not all of them are enemies.

It only aired on TV and is pretty hard to come by as a result. It's generally available on Youtube, but any given link doesn't stick around for long due to copyright takedowns.

Comment: Can you (or anyone else) point to the time in the youtube video where we see a xenomorph-like alien, or a fanged frisbee, or a jetpack scene on a bridge?

Comment: I have not had a chance to watch all of it, but this does look familiar and I have found bits where the Predator-like alien leaps off with a jetpack type of departure. Around the 48 minute mark, they're crossing a log, the alien attacks, and then leaps off with a body with his jetpack. That may be what I've mashed together in my head. And I could be wrong about the frisbee thing...

Comment: Also, there is now a TV Tropes entry: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/CodeRedTheRubiconConspiracy

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like perhaps Alien vs. Predator?

Comment: Definitely not the actual franchise, and this predated the crossover movie. Plus, neither of the AvP movies had either a jetpack or a talk show.

Comment: Just to amend this, the talk show is from a different movie than the first one.