# Pre-2000 movie set in present time about body-consuming aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a sci-fi movie set in the present time with nukes, bodysucking alien monsters out of control, and an alien who wants to help.

Just splinters from my memory, so:

- Usual plot: some people for some reason in an isolated place on Earth (isolated means far from civilization, in a jungle and/or in an island);
- Played in the present (late XXs, early XXIs);
- Most of them are soldiers/troops, but I am not sure about that;
- There is an exotic woman with darker skin and in military uniform, proportional body;
- They met with some strange monsters later face to face (approximately 1-3 meters in size); one of their first appearances are when the creature sucks with at least two tentacles one dude from the group, on the tree, rather disturbing scene;
- There is a friendly alien, a humanoid, but with a reptilian-like face, and there are some trolling conversations between people and him. Like:

  "oops, those creatures are from your world? we won't send cockroaches to you" / other chat with the alien, its replying question was: "is there a problem with my sense of humor?"

  These texts were dubbed in my language, I tried to translate back.
- Finally, an (ground nuclear bomb's?) explosion solved all at the end, vanishing some part of the island/forest, in cooperation with the alien.

The movie had been made between 1980-200x. Not *Alien* franchise, not *Predator* franchise.

Seems to be rare, hard to find any clue.

Answer (score 5):

This is likely *[Code Red - The Rubicon Conspiracy](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/CodeRedTheRubiconConspiracy)*, a TV Film from 2001.

[image: Code Red poster]

> Code Red: the Rubicon Conspiracy is a 2001 TV movie aired by UPN involving a dishonorably discharged Army Lieutenant by the name of Peter Doyle (played by Brian McNamara) who is called in for a rescue mission regarding the Rubicon Station in the midst of Africa. His brother, James Doyle, may be the last remaining member of the last mission squad. He was also the reason for Peter's discharge, The Rubicon Station has a nuclear failsafe due to detonate in 20 hours if it's not reset and there are local rebels in play. Furthermore, Doyle quickly learns that some of his opposition is not from this planet, but not all of them are enemies.

I don't have a source of text to quote chapter and verse at you, but it involves a military squad in a jungle (set in Africa, filmed in Australia) and Lt. Joyce Darwin is indeed a bit darker-skinned and exotic-looking. They encounter a tentacled creature which sucks life-force out of people, and they are helped by a more humanoid figure. And the proposed solution from the start was a nuclear failsafe, although the ending employs more conventional explosives.

Comment: If so, it is a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84078/1990s-film-knockoff-of-alien-and-predator-franchises-included-a-jetpack-and-a. :) And, if so, don't forget to click on the checkmark to accept and so we can close it as a Duplicate.