# Name of a movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I need help remembering the name of a movie, I've only seen it twice. All I remember was there were US military men, and an invisible alien, I don't believe it was apart of the predator movies. I'm thinking its an old movie, and most the time they were in a forest like area.The alien also had a device to translate his language so the humans could understand him so they could help him find his ship and he could go home. Anyone know of the movie I'm talking about?

Comment: Can you say when the movie was made? 1990's? 2000's? 1970's? Remember any actors or actresses? Remember the director or studio? Was it made in the US? Was it made in Europe?

Comment: I have no idea. The best I can recall is maybe the locals in the movie called the alien a "river spirit". But that could be another movie

Comment: There was another thing, it brought "bugs" to the planet. They were unintentionally deadly to humans. And I mean "unintentionally" because I remember the alien being slightly confused when it heard the humans were being killed by them.

Comment: The alien was a tall humanoid, yet reptilian creature. I "believe" that it was extremely fast, like run across the water of the river fast.

Comment: For your future reference:  This is not a very well-written [tag:story-identification] question.  **(A)** The title is far too broadly descriptive; it should say something about the movie and not simply that you are asking a question about one.  **(B)** Please read [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) for help when asking such [tag:story-identification] questions in future. **(C)** I thought I should repeat the first one for emphasis:  A title like this one is not very useful for helping other people help you; please be more descriptive in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be *[Code Red: the Rubicon Conspiracy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0266414/?ref_=fn_al_tt_10)* as per the answer to my question at [1990s film, knockoff of Alien and Predator franchises, included a jetpack and a fanged frisbee](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84078/1990s-film-knockoff-of-alien-and-predator-franchises-included-a-jetpack-and-a/94566#94566)?

That had a forest, an alien, military, and the transported "bugs".

Comment: Yes! I believe that's it!!  Thank you!!